# How do I swap between forms using buttons on my Master Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, webforms, master-pages

I'm using C# to try to create a set of web pages. I'm trying to use buttons on the master page to swap between forms, but no methods I've tried seem to be working. How would I go about swapping pages using buttons?

Comment: Swap between forms? In aspnet there is only one "form". Please update your question because now it is not clear at all.

Comment: I was under the understanding there is only one active form, but all of the pages are webforms.

Comment: If you put it like that it makes sense. But that makes your question not clearer... Add some code, describe the problem in details and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: don't worry, I found further info and answered my own question below. Maybe this can make what I was asking more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Alright sorry for the lack of clarity in my question. I did some more investigating and found I could use this in the button event handler:

```
Response.Redirect("FormYouWantToSwitchTo.aspx");
```

This will move you to the "FormYouWantToSwitchTo" page